# Hash code of string is broken in .NET Core 2.1, but works in 2.0

Tags: c#, string, .net-core, hashcode

I recently upgraded one of my projects from .NET Core 2.0 to .NET Core 2.1. After doing so several of my tests started to fail.

After narrowing this down I've found that in .NET Core 2.1 it is not possible to compute the hash code of a string using a culture aware comparer with the string sort compare option.

I've created a test that reproduce my problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_compute_hash_code_using_invariant_string_sort_comparer()
{
    var compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
    var stringComparer = compareInfo.GetStringComparer(CompareOptions.StringSort);
    stringComparer.GetHashCode("test"); // should not throw!
}
```

I've tested it on a couple of frameworks with the following results:

- .NET Core 2.0: **✔ PASS**
- .NET Core 2.1: **✖ FAIL**
- .NET Framework 4.7: **✖ FAIL**
- .NET Framework 4.6.2: **✖ FAIL**

When failing an `ArgumentException` is thrown from `CompareInfo.GetHashCodeOfString` saying:

> Value of flags is invalid

Now, to my questions:

1. Why is it not allowed to use `CompareOptions.StringSort` when computing a hash code?
2. Why was it allowed in .NET Core 2.0?`

As far as I understand `CompareOptions.StringSort` only affects the relative sort order of strings and should not affect hash code computation. MSDN says:

> *StringSort* Indicates that the string comparison must use the string sort algorithm. In a string sort, the hyphen and the apostrophe, as well as other nonalphanumeric symbols, come before alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Maybe a question for GitHub?

Comment: @TheGeneral care to elaborate?

Comment: I think you're questions will be better answered by the .net core team themselves on the GitHub project (https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues) rather than StackOverflow, because this sounds like a bug with the framework and not necessarily your code.

Comment: .NET Core is Open Source and lives in GitHub, where the .Net Code Jedi and oompa loompas work tirelessly to make you happy

Comment: I think he means that if you've found a bug with .NET Core, you should report it as such, or submit a PR to fix it.

Comment: Leave the question open, someone might chime in, and or update us if you get a response

Comment: The issue might be that https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e2bcca7d9d0e36510eaba9b1028e16a5de39cee9/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Globalization/CompareInfo.cs#L53 and https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e2bcca7d9d0e36510eaba9b1028e16a5de39cee9/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/StringComparer.cs#L177 are out of sync?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug issue that is being tracked now on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corefx team has [confirmed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/33154) that this is a bug in .NET Core 2.1 and also in the full .NET Framework as of 4.6+.

They also acknowledge that it will be hard to change this behavior in the full framework and may therefore consider to keep the behavior as-is in .NET Core 2.1+ to maintain consistency between .NET Core and the full framework.

A possible workaround is to use a class like this:

```
internal sealed class CultureAwareStringSortComparer : StringComparer
{
    public CultureAwareStringSortComparer(
        CompareInfo compareInfo, 
        CompareOptions options = CompareOptions.StringSort)
    {
        Requires.ArgNotNull(compareInfo, nameof(compareInfo));
        this.SortComparer = compareInfo.GetStringComparer(options);
        this.HashCodeComparer = compareInfo.GetStringComparer(
            options & ~CompareOptions.StringSort);
    }

    internal StringComparer SortComparer { get; }

    internal StringComparer HashCodeComparer { get; }

    public override int Compare(string x, string y) => this.SortComparer.Compare(x, y);

    public override bool Equals(string x, string y) => this.SortComparer.Equals(x, y);

    public override int GetHashCode(string obj) => this.HashCodeComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
}
```